# Is output of Apache-licensed software Apache-licensed?

Tags: apache-2.0

If I  use the output of Apache v2 licenced software do I have to adhere to stating changes?  Also if  I only copy    3-4 lines of apache code into my project with large number of files and code do I still need to adhere to  its terms?

Answer (score 4):

> If I use the output of Apache v2 licenced software do I have to adhere to stating changes?

As we [have already said](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8058/458), the licence on a piece of software does not *generally* extend to its output.

> Also if I only copy 3-4 lines of apache code into my project with large number of files and code do I still need to adhere to its terms?

That will depend on whether you've copied enough material to require a copyright licence in order to do so lawfully.  Whether three or four lines are enough to qualify for copyright protection is not an easy question to give a definitive answer to.  If it were held to be the "*expressive heart of the work*" then less than three lines can qualify for protection; conversely, if it were three or four lines of boilerplate header code, such as one would often see in other programs, it is unlikely so to qualify.  We really can't help you decide which applies in your case, since we're not judges.

However, since the requirements of the Apache licence are not particularly onerous, why not follow them anyway, just to be on the safe side?